# tsvector type does not exist in Postgres 8.2.15 - how to fix?

Tags: postgresql

I've been working on setting up a Greenplum DB with the server VM at

https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb

This VM runs Greenplum on Postgres 8.2.15.

I need to set up a text search vector (tsvector) index for one of my tables. See

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSVECTOR

for a specification on tsvector.

If I add a tsvector column to a table or create a table with a tsvector column, it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  type "tsvector" does not exist
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL 8.2, the full-text search features were an extension module. See [contrib/tsearch2 in the Pg docs for relevant historical information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tsearch2.html). I can't link to the 8.2 docs because they've been removed from the site as too obsolete to be relevant.

It's possible that Greenplum might include this module and have it available to load. Look for `tsearch2`. If it doesn't, then you can't use full-text search.